# Best practices C# creating file in test

Tags: c#, .net, file

How and where can I create a file (in a test) which can be used and created by everyone on standard windows 7/8 platform ?

Because when I try to use:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(TEST_FILE_PATH);
```

I've got an UnauthorizedAccessException so I can change my rights on my computer but not the rights of the other contributors.

EDIT:

Allright, you need some details. I've got an interface wich permit me to take a stream. But in my test, I need to use a file, read it and store what i'm reading. So, I want to test that all data in the file are correctly stored.

Example :

```
        ICarStorage carStorage = new CarFileStorage(FILE_PATH);
        List<Car> cars = carStorage.Load();
        // array which contains cars wrote in file
        int expected = CARS.Length;
        int actual = cars.Count;
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by test, a unit test?

Comment: Ok but how to test that the file is correctly loaded (as my load method should) ?! @GrantWinney

Answer (score 4):

A "test" should not actually access a file. Your API should not access a file. Who knows, your user might not have a file or might not want to use a file, just like you in your test scenario.

You need something abstract that represents a stream of data you can read or write to. In C#, this is called a [Stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.io.stream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The user of your API can then decide to pass in a [file stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx), or maybe a [memory stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.io.memorystream(v=vs.110).aspx) using only RAM. Or even a [network stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream(v=vs.110).aspx) coming from a socket. Or any other kind you never thought about.

Comment: so far its not clear what kind of test he is executing, you're right for unit tests, but in other cases this is a valid scenario

Comment: @MichaelSander Building a better API is *always* a valid scenario. Do you know a single method in the .NET framework that would take a filename if it does not absolutely have to? Streams is the concept to solve this problem, it's only the unit test where it happens to surface.

Comment: This is great advice but it does not answer the question. Even if the OP decides to go with this advice future visitors probably want to see an actual answer.

Comment: Aye, I know a couple, like XDocument.Load(string uri) I'm just sayig we dont have enough information to answer

Comment: @usr I'm indeed thinking that "best practice for creating file in test" is "don't, use streams instead". So this *is* an answer.

Comment: @MichaelSander You do realize, that the exact function you name has an overload for Streams and Readers of various kinds, don't you? With *that* API, you would not have the problem the OP has. Because it offers streams.

Comment: Please see EDIT, i give more details @MichaelSander

Comment: @usr : more details now

Comment: @kaoziun why did you ping me in that comment? Maybe you should comment on my answer. If it is useless to you I'll delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the temp folder. For example using `Path.GetTempFileName()`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not sure what would best suit your needs, but I would put it like this:

The `UnauthorizedAccessException` is most probably caused by test running in different context, short, you are probably using a path where not all users running the tests having access to.

Lets assume you only have this single file and don't want to spend to much effort into frameworking, then you could create yourself a file name out of `Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetTempFileName())`.

What I'm doing within bigger applications: I'll never let anyone access the file system directly. Instead I have a set of tools that are used via dependency injection, that do all the file access stuff. As a result, I'll never have to check files in a test, I can mock it all away, except for the test of the file system tools of course.